# Why does NOT give an unexpected result when flipping 1?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

I am currently learning the process of bitwise operators, and I've come across something that I can't quite figure out.

Im currently working with the NOT(~) operator, which should invert all of the bits. So in order to get a better understanding of it, I've tried creating a program that will flip the number 1's bits.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1; // 0001 in binary
    int y = ~x; // should flip the bits, so its 1110, or 14
    cout << y; 
}
```

However, when running this, i am getting -2 as the result. Can anyone offer an explanation as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Where you have written, in a comment, `0001 in binary`, how did you decide that there should be exactly three leading `0`s? Also: how do you imagine that negative numbers are represented in binary? Have you heard of *two's complement*?

Comment: This question's title should make it an excellent landing point for future Askers.

Comment: `int y = ~x & 0b1111;`

Answer (score 6):

You're using signed integers. Your expected result (14) would occur if you were using unsigned integers (and if the integer were only 4 bits, which it is not).

Instead, with signed integers, all values with the highest bit set are negative values - that's how [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works. For example, if you have 16 bits, then values `0b0000_0000_0000_0000` through `0b0111_1111_1111_1111` are assigned to the positive values ("0" through "32767") meanwhile values `0b1000_0000_0000_0000` through `0b1111_1111_1111_1111` are assigned to the negative values ("-32768" through "-1").

Also, `int` usually is more than 4 bits; it's often 32-bits. The negation of 1 would be `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110`, not `0b1110`.

`0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110` when treated as a signed integer is `-2` using the Two's Complement rules.

`0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110` when treated as an unsigned integer is `4,294,967,294`, equal to `2^32 - 2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>

// Program prints the following:
//   unsigned int_8:   254
//   signed   int_8:   -2
//   unsigned int_16   65534
//   signed   int_16   -2
//   unsigned int_32   4294967294
//   signed   int_32   -2

int main() {
    printf( "unsigned int_8:   %hhu\n", (uint8_t)~1 );
    printf( "signed   int_8:   %d\n", (int8_t)~1 );

    printf( "unsigned int_16   %hu\n", (uint16_t)~1 );
    printf( "signed   int_16   %d\n", (int16_t)~1 );

    printf( "unsigned int_32   %u\n", (uint32_t)~1 );
    printf( "signed   int_32   %d\n", (int32_t)~1 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried 
uint16_t (unsigned 16 bit) for x
uint16_t x = 1;
x = ~x
which results in the max value it can hold -1 (65534), along with the 32 bit variation.

additionally, ive just gone with unsigned int x = 1 which gives a similar output(respecting their ranges)

Comment: "Hi, I've tried uint16_t (unsigned 16 bit) for x uint16_t x = 1; x = ~x which results in the max value it can hold -1 (65534)" Okay; and *are you confused* by this result? If so, *why*? What did you expect *instead*? Why?